# Why is OK greyed out in my Raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, macos

[image]

I cannot figure out why I cannot click OK on my Raster Calculator. It might be important to note I am on MACBOOK PRO.

Comment: Is your Output layer folder location valid?

Comment: Try adding .tif to the end of the file name